# Как выводить результаты ajax-запросов по порядку

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsonp

Работа с API. Есть некий массив addresstag который содержит адреса запросов. С помощью ajax и функции myLoop посылаются запросы через каждые 300 милисекунд. На выходе ответы записыватся в отдельные div-ы и нужно их выводить по поряку. Но Проблема в том, что ответы приходят не по порядку, а вразнобой: где результатов по запросу оказалось меньше, этот ответ и выводит первее. Как выводить ответы именно в той последовательности, в которой были посланы запросы?

Вот часть кода js:

```
var r = 0;                     
$('results_5').empty();

function myLoop () {          
  setTimeout(function () {    
    newURL = addresstag[r]; 

    $.ajax({
      url: newURL,
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function(data) {
        if (data.ok) { 
          if (data.count > 0) {
            $('<div class="myresults" ></div>').text(data.count).appendTo('results_5');
          } else {
            $('<p>No results.</p>').appendTo('results_5');
          }
        } else {
          $('results_5').empty();
          alert(data.error);
        }
      }
    });          
    r++;      
    if (r < addresstag.length) {            
      myLoop();          
    }           
  }, 300)
}

myLoop();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно применить несколько подходов, самый простой, как мне кажется — добавлять div до отправки запроса, но делать его невидимым, а когда приходит ответ — добавлять в него контент и показывать:

```
var r = 0;                     
$('.results_5').empty();

function myLoop () {          
  setTimeout(function () {    
    var newURL = addresstag[r];

    var $resultDiv = $('<div></div>');
    $resultDiv.hide();
    $resultDiv.appendTo('.results_5');

    $.ajax({
      url: newURL,
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function(data) {
        if (data.ok) {
          if (data.count > 0) {
            $resultDiv.addClass('myresults');
            $resultDiv.text(data.count);
          } else {
            $resultDiv.text('No results.');
          }

          $resultDiv.show();
        } else {
          $('.results_5').empty();
          alert(data.error);
        }
      }
    });          
    r++;      
    if (r < addresstag.length) {            
      myLoop();          
    }           
  }, 300)
}

myLoop();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
success: (function(index) { // 0. capture current r value through parameter index
  return function(data) {
    if (data.ok) {
      // 1. create element that displays result received through the current ajax
      var $res = (data.count > 0)?
        $('<div class="myresults" data-index="' + index + '"></div>').text(data.count) : 
        $('<p class="myresults" data-index="' + index + '">No results.</p>');

      // 2. find the element with index just before the one currently handled
      $prev = null;
      $allResults = $("results_5 .myresults");
      for (var i = 0; i < $allResults; i++) {
        if (+$allResults.eq(i).data("index") > index) {
          break;
        }
        $prev = $allResults.eq(i);
      }

      // 3. add current result to DOM
      ($prev == null)? $res.appendTo('results_5') : $prev.after($res);
    } else {
      $('results_5').empty();
      alert(data.error);
    }
  };
})(r)
```